# Avoid "if ... is.. " for complex interactions of derived classes

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism, implementation

Lets say I have a base class A, and classes B and C implement A

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract bool interact(A a);
}
```

Is there a nice way to avoid "if" clauses inside the implementations of interact(A) in case where interact(A) depends on the derived class?

I want to avoid

```
class B : A
{
    public bool interact(A a)
    {
        if(a is B)
        {
        }
        else if (a is C)
        {
        }
        else if ...
        ....
    }
}
```

Context: 
In my case I want to test for collisions of various shapes. If a circle is colliding with a square, a half circle colliding with a triangle... . I have the base class "Shape" (above represented by A) and the method "hitBy(Shape s)" (above represented by interact(A a)). The algorithms for detecting eg circle to circle collisions is completely different from eg triangle to rectangle collision.
My idea was to simply be able to call shape1.hitBy(shape2) to test for collisions.

Comment: You should likely have multiple abstract methods (one that accepts each derived type).  Then in each derived type you define how they interact.  You can refactor your code into helper classes or extension methods to prevent any repeated logic.  But without knowing more context its hard to give direction on the DRY refactoring

Comment: If I understand your logic correctly, these classes shouldn't be interacting with each other in this way.  That is separate logic.  For example if you have a Bear class and a Fish class, it doesn't make sense how they interact with each other on the classes them selves because who is the "owner" of the logic.  Consume() and Die() might exist on each, but something else need to understand how they react regardless of order `eat(fish, bear)` or `eat(bear, fish)` should be the same.

Comment: Eric Lippert has a 5 posts blog series about this subject called [Wizards and warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). The conclusion is quite the same as what Erik Philips wrote in his comment - this type of interaction belongs in a different class.